# How do I set English UK as my display language in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, input-languages

My PC's default display language is currently set to English(US). I want to change it to English(UK) but whenever I go to settings in order to choose the language of my choice I see this:

[image: B4FiX.png]

English UK is unavailable. Why?

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/language-packs#lptabs=win10

Comment: @JosefZ I have already tried that. Still says UK English is unavailable. Pretty much all Non-US varieties of English ,in fact.

Comment: What version of Windows 10 do you have?  Only Windows 10 Home, Windows 10 Professional, Windows 10 Enterprise, and Windows 10 Education can install multiple language packs.

Answer (score 3):

> There are advanced language settings that may block the download of
> language packs. To revert these settings to their defaults values so
> that you can download language packs, follow these steps:
>
> - Open Control Panel. To do this, type Control Panel in the **Search** box, and then tap or click **Control Panel** in the search results list.
> - Tap or click **Clock, Language and Region**. (If you are viewing Control Panel in icon display, select Language, and then go to step
>   4.)
> - Tap or click **Language**.
> - Tap or click **Advanced settings**.
> - Examine the **Override for Windows display language** and **Override for default input method lists**. Make sure that the **Use language list** (recommended) option is selected for both lists (see
>   Figure 1). Then, tap or click **Save**.
>
> Figure 1: Advanced settings:
>
> [image]
> <sub>(source: [microsoft.com](https://support.microsoft.com/Library/Images/2911142.JPG))</sub>

> - After you save the settings, you are returned to the standard language settings. In the list of previously installed languages,
>   click **Options** next to the language you want to install.
> - Click the download link to install the language pack (see Figure 2).
>
> Figure 2: Start the download:
>
> [image]

**Taken From :**

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2910256